# Hiding columns from 2 ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have to hide columns when a range is empty, and I have 2 ranges in different sheets to control when to hide or unhide these columns.
I'm trying to use a FOR loop with 2 variables, but i's not working, this is my code:

```
Sub HiddenColumns()

    Dim HiddenColumn1 As Range
    Dim HiddenColumn2 As Range

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range


    Set HiddenColumn1 = Range("rngColumnHidden")
    Set HiddenColumn2 = Range("rngColumnHidden2")

    For Each c In HiddenColumn1
        For Each d In HiddenColumn2

            If c.Value = "" Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                If d.Value = "" Then
                d.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            End If
        Next d
    Next c

End Sub
```

With one range it's working perfectly, but when I try to hide another range, I have problems, this is the code for one range:

```
Sub HiddenColumns()

    Dim HiddenColumn1 As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set HiddenColumn1 = Range("rngColumnHidden")
    For Each c In HiddenColumn1

            If c.Value = "" Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it's not working"? it gives error or doesnt hide what you think it should hide? I tried your first code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: The way things are setup now, `HiddenColumn` will be hidden if `c` is empty but `HiddenColumn2` will only be hidden if both `c` and `d` and empty. Are those the conditions you want?

Comment: it gives error in the line: d.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Comment: I really want to hide HiddenColumn and HiddenColumn2 independently...

Comment: what is the error? and how do you have defined range "rngColumnHidden2"?

Comment: The error is type mismatch, and I have defined the range

Comment: as I already mentioned the code works for me but if I create some #REF or #DIV/0! in the range it uses to check for empty cells it gives me Type mismatch error, so I would probably check the ranges

Comment: Thanks! it's working now with a range of one row and with no #N/A in the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited after OP's comment

don't nest loops

```
Sub HiddenColumns()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("rngColumnHidden").Rows(1).Cells
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = "")
    Next c

    For Each c In Range("rngColumnHidden2").Rows(1).Cells
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = "")
    Next c
End Sub
```

and for the sake of avoiding code repetitions you could use a helper sub and code

```
Sub HiddenColumns()
    HideColumns Range("rngColumnHidden")
    HideColumns Range("rngColumnHidden2")
End Sub

Sub HideColumns(columnsRng As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In columnsRng.Rows(1).Cells
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = "")
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It's giving me an error in the second: 'c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = "")' the error is type mismatch

Comment: this most probably is not issue of the code, but the value in the cell. Are you sure there are no errors?

Comment: maybe your named ranges are not "1 rowed", so see edited answer

Comment: yes! I defined the second range with 2 rows, i didn't realize! I think it will be enough with one row, as the columns are the same... thanks! now it's working!

Comment: @DisplayName: out of curiosity - you were able to replicate the error when the range is defined with more than one row? I am stumped why it is working fine for me with only "Range("rngColumnHidden")". Yes it goes through both the rows if I defined it with 2 rows so it is not really logical, but it never gives me any error so I am trying to figure out what I did differently. Thanks